# I am getting and interesting error in Eclipse and unsure how to fix it

Tags: java, eclipse, audio

This is the error I am getting from the code bellow.
**Error:**

```
Usage: org.jitsi.examples.AVReceive2 <args>
Valid args:
  --local-port-base= The port on which media is to be received. The specified value will be used as the port to receive the audio RTP on, the next port after it will be used to receive the audio RTCP on. Respectively, the subsequent ports will be used to receive the video RTP and RTCP on.
  --remote-host= The name of the host from which the media is to be received.
  --remote-port-base= The port from which media is to be received. The specified vaue will be used as the port to receive the audio RTP from, the next port after it will be used to receive the audio RTCP from. Respectively, the subsequent ports will be used to receive the video RTP and RTCP from.
```

**All the code I have:**

```
package com.hexicle.DiscordBot;

import me.itsghost.jdiscord.DiscordAPI;
import me.itsghost.jdiscord.DiscordBuilder;
import me.itsghost.jdiscord.exception.BadUsernamePasswordException;
import me.itsghost.jdiscord.exception.DiscordFailedToConnectException;

public class MyBot {

    private DiscordAPI api;

    public MyBot()
    {
        api = new DiscordBuilder().build();
    }

    public void connect()
    {
        try {
            api.login("", "");
        } catch (BadUsernamePasswordException | DiscordFailedToConnectException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyBot bot = new MyBot();
        bot.connect();
    }

}
```

I am not very experienced with Java so this might be super easy! Thanks!

Comment: It's not an error, it's a usage display, and you got to wonder why it says `org.jitsi.examples.AVReceive2` when your class is `com.hexicle.DiscordBot.MyBot` (FYI: bad package name, should be all lowercase). Are you sure you're running this class?

Comment: Please explain more. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Looks like you're executing class `org.jitsi.examples.AVReceive2`, not class `com.hexicle.DiscordBot.MyBot`, and the `AVReceive2` class has required command-line arguments.

Comment: Sorry I am new. I eclipse with the file MyBot.java open I hit play. So am I executing the right file. **EDIT:** Oh I just released what I was doing wrong.  It turns out it was executing the wrong file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If the problem was transient and/or user error, please close or delete the question; it's of no value to the community any more.